# how to get javascript calender value on server side

Tags: asp.net

I am new on Asp.net. I am using Javascript calender It use Input tag.if I use `runat="server"` so that I can get value on cs page then it does not display calender. How can I get calender value from input tag to .cs page

Comment: How are you getting calendar value in js.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

Have a hidden field on your control.
Set its in javascript by using :

$('#<%=hdDate.ClientID %>').val("date value here");

and then you can access this hidden field in cs file.

Answer (score 0):

create a hidden field as in your aspx page which should be runat="server".

then

On button click call javascript function say jsOnclikfun() and write this function as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jsOnclikfun() {
        var dateInputtext = document.getElementById("Id Of input textbox which you are trying to make runat=server");

        var hdDateValue = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenField_Id.ClientID %>');

        hdDateValue.value = dateInputtext.value;

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Now on server side where ever you need data get it from that hidden field as hiddenfieldID.Value.

Hope this helps.